# How to use htmltext for DataTextField in DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net

I have a DropDownList and set a DataSource for it.

html:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODScategory"  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" Width="200px">
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODScategory" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllByCommand"TypeName="Alian.BusinessLayer.clsCustomerCategoryFactory">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="FatherID is not null" Name="SQLWhere" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
   </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

My datasource is a table with two column(ID,Name). i save htmltext in Name.

for example :

ID    Name

1     Cofee span style="color: DarkOrange">A

2     span style="background-color: LightSalmon">Hotel>

My problem is : when i use this table for dropdowndatasource, my value show with html tag.

[image]

How do remove html tag??

Answer (score 3):

if I understood you  correctly, you try to apply some style for your dropdownlist options.
in this case You need to add your style for every item in your dropdownlist item collection.
Item style you can store in name with some separator  for instance ';' "color:red; YourItem Name" (N.B. But I don't think that is good idea)

```
foreach(ListItem item in ddl.Items)
{
   string[] data=item.Text.Split(';');
   item.Attributes.Add("style", data[0]);
   item.Text=data[1];
}
```

and you can do it for example on Page_PreRender.
But you have to be careful because not all browsers correctly supported style attribute for tag option.

Remove unwanted html tags from server-side:

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(<.+>)\b|(<\/.+>)");

foreach(ListItem item in ddl.Items)
{
   item.Text=reg.Replace(item.Text," ");
}
```

You can do this replacement in your data source, but I don't know which type of this you use

If you want to remove unwanted html tags from client side with javascript:

solution with Jquery using

```
function RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag()
{
   $('select:[id*="elementSelectId"] > option').each(function(){var _self=$(this);   _self.text(_self.text().replace(/<[^>]+>/g,' '));});
}
```

without Jquery

```
function RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag()
{
  var _arr=document.getElementById('elementSelectId').childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<_arr.length;i++)
    { 
         if(_arr[i].text!=undefined)
           { _arr[i].text=(_arr[i].text).replace(/<[^>]+>/g,' ');
                     _arr[i].value=(_arr[i].value).replace(/<[^>]+>/g,' ');
                    }

     }

}
```

start your javascript function on page load:

Jquery

```
 $(documet).ready{RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag();}
```

without jquery

```
 document.body.onload=function(){RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag();}
```

if Sys object is present on page ( this method useful if your drop down list is located inside some updatepanel)

```
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag);
```

all code in cs file:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag")
        {
            string script = @"function RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag()
{
 var _arr=document.getElementById('"+ddlcategory.ClientID+"').childNodes;
 for (var i=0;i<_arr.length;i++)
{ if(_arr[i].text!=undefined)
    { _arr[i].text=(_arr[i].text).replace(/<[^>]+>/g,' ');
              _arr[i].value=(_arr[i].value).replace(/<[^>]+>/g,' ');// if text is same  with value
            }
}
}
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag); ";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),  "RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag", script, true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, plz see my item in image. they are contain html tag, and i want to  remove html tag from them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you in first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot,elementSelectId is myDropdownlist? I use javascript code but don't run my function, i use a alert but dont show alert!

Comment: yes, elementSelectId  is id attribute of your select tag < select id="elementSelectId"> or from serverside you can define this  <%# ddl.ClientID %> or you havn't id you can find your dropdown by attribute name

Comment: Thanks , i use document.getElementById('<%# ddlcategory.ClientID %>') but don't find.

Comment: but this '<%= ddlcategory.ClientID %>'

Comment: And I fixed some small bugs in may javascript code.  (i<_arr.length:) --->   (i<_arr.length;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this javascript code. when i use alert the value change but show oldvalue in dropdownlist :(

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag();
        }
        function RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag()
        {
            var _arr = document.getElementById('<%= ddlcategory.ClientID %>');
            alert(_arr);
            for (var i = 0; i < _arr.length;i++)
            { 
                if(_arr[i].text!=undefined)
                {
                    _arr[i].text = (_arr[i].text).replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
                    alert(_arr[i].text);
                }
            }

        }
    </script>

Comment: Sorry, forgot about childNodes. I fixed script

Comment: You can add event  on your dropdownlist like this: document.getElementById('<%= ddlcategory.ClientID %>').addEventListener("click", function(){ RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag();}, false);   And insert it befor  RemoveUnwantedHTMLTag() function declaration

Comment: You can use 'load' event in addEventListener function instead of 'click'

Comment: I use this javascript in html but don't change items

Comment: Add, please,  this line of code:   _arr[i].value=_arr[i].value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'');

Comment: Thanks, i don't use it because my value is ID of table.